# Finding ZFS .zfs/snapshots directory in OpenSolaris

Tags: zfs, opensolaris, snapshot

My home directory in OpenSolaris 0906 is part of the zpool rpool. I can view the pool in `zpool list`. I can view the file system in `zfs list`. I can create snapshots. I can use `zfs list` and see a list of the snapshots I've taken. It's my understanding there should be a *.zfs* directory inside */export/home/test* at */export/home/test/.zfs*

---

```
zfs snapshot rpool/export/home/test@1
```

creates my snapshot successfully

---

```
zfs list -t snapshot
```

shows my snapshots successfully

---

I can't figure out where to find the snapshots. I see no *.zfs* directory anywhere.

Any hints where else I should look or what else I should do to find the *.zfs* directory and the snapshots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the snapdir property of the dataset if you need to make it visible.

```
# ls -la /rpool/
total 6
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4 2010-09-14 05:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 25 2010-11-18 13:18 ..
dr-xr-xr-x  4 root root  4 2010-09-14 05:15 .zfs
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  3 2010-09-14 05:15 boot
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  3 2010-09-14 05:21 etc

# zfs set snapdir=hidden rpool

# ls -la /rpool/
total 6
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4 2010-09-14 05:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 25 2010-11-18 13:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  3 2010-09-14 05:15 boot
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  3 2010-09-14 05:21 etc
```

Comment: Making this directory visible isn't a recommended practice. It isn't necessary as even when the snapdir property is set to hidden, you can still access it. http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6399899

Comment: what are the downsides of making it visible? I don't think there is a recommended practice about this. every org should decide how they want to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

The snapshot directory should be in /export/home/test/.zfs.

This directory doesn't appear with a simple "ls -a", you need to specify it explicitly.